# REST on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, iis

I'm wondering how many folks using the Microsoft development stack (IIS and/or ASP.NET) are actually using REST?  If so, what forms of rest are being used?

REST can be categorized a zillion ways, but for the purpose of this question I'll categorize it as follows:

1. Radically REST:  Using all the
   HTTP methods PUT/POST/GET/DELETE
2. Moderate REST: Using GET/POST
3. REST Hybrid: Uses just the GET or
   POST HTTP method, but follows
   RESTful principles of addressability
   and state.

In a class I'm teaching we've been trying to implement a "radically RESTful" service on IIS, but we've been having difficulty implementing the PUT method. There doesn't seem to be a lot of buzz on implementing PUT on IIS so I'm wondering how many people are actually using full blown REST?  Are you using REST?

Comment: implementing a put http verb doesn't sound particularly cutting edge. i would assume if you added a http handler it would see put requests coming in.

Comment: Were you aware that IIS has little to do with ASP.NET these days? You seem to equate the two.

Comment: The point of my question was that I'm interested in what people using Microsoft technologies are doing. Rephrased to make more sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think part of the reason for the lack of buzz around REST on the IIS stack has been Microsoft's original adoption of SOAP as the way, truth and light when it came to web services - especially with Windows Communication Foundation being heavily SOAP focused.

They went on to release the [WCF REST Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx), to follow on from the release of .NET 3.5, and also the ADO.NET data services that are part of .NET 3.5 SP1.

As [Magnus points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172728/33051), Microsoft have since released the [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) which builds on the features of the ASP.NET MVC platform to provide a unified approach to RESTful services on IIS.

> ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is an ideal platform for building RESTful applications on the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 11):

I'm involved in a project that uses WCF REST on IIS, but of course I'd recommend having a look at the framework I built: OpenRasta is a .net open-source stack that makes implementing REST much easier.

Google is your friend. The main site is http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta.

Answer (score 4):

The WCF Rest Toolkit mentioned in the answer from "Zhaph - Ben Duguid" is now deprecated.
It has now been replaced with the [WCF Web API project](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP).

Edit: Which is now also deprecated and replaced by ASP.NET Web API!

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you approach it.

By default IIS will limit verbs to ASP.NET pages to GET, HEAD, POST and DEBUG. You are, of course, free to tell it to accept PUT as well by editing the handler mapping. Assuming you wanted your own extension you'd do something like

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="*.example" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, DEBUG"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

If you want to remap .aspx you, of course, can in much the same way, assuming the server is configured to allow you/

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services uses RESTful services. It might be worth checking out... aside from being restful, it's a really cool tech.

Here's an extract from a white paper on it:

> The goal of Microsoft® ADO.NET Data Services is to enable applications to expose data as a data service that can be consumed by web clients within corporate networks and across the internet. A data service is reachable via regular HTTP requests, using standard HTTP verbs such as GET, POST, PUT and DELETE to perform CRUD operations against the service. The payload format used by the service is controllable by the application, but all options are simple, open formats such as JSON and Atom/APP.

Here's a [white paper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907912.aspx) and it's [home page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) (at least what I think is it's home page)

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 1):

What version of IIS? In IIS6 you need to enable WebDAV to enable PUSH requests to get through (no, I don't think that makes much sense either :-)). I don't think that's the case in IIS7 though.

Comment: by default IIS 7 refuses PUT requests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the .Net class, HttpListener, which is the IIS web server engine(http.sys) without the IIS admin tools.  I am handling all of the HTTP verbs.  You can add attach the ASP.Net runtime to this if you like, but you don't need to.

In fact in a few cases we implemented a version of PATCH as an experiment. Once you get down to the basics, the verb is simply a string in one of the HTTP headers.

You actually cannot categorize REST in a zillion ways.  There are may ways of using HTTP to build distributed applications but there is only [one](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) definition of REST.